# problems using npm serialport and npm mysql together

Tags: mysql, node.js

i'm trying to read the serialport using npm serialport and insert that data into a mysql database.

- reading the serialport works fine.
- inserting data into a database also works.
- but for some reason reading the serialport and inserting it into a database does not work

this works

```
    var serialport = require('serialport');
    var Readlines = serialport.parsers.Readline;
    var parser = new Readlines();
    var path = '/dev/ttyACM0' ;
    var myPort = new serialport(path ,{
        baudRate: 9600,
    });

    myPort.pipe(parser);
    parser.on('data', readSerialData);

    function readSerialData(data) {
        console.log(data);
        sleep(1000);
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

this works

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "testdb"
    });

    var data = 55;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Temperature_Sensor (value) VALUES ("+ data 
    +")";  
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("record inserted");
    });
```

this does not work

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "testdb"
    });

    var serialport = require('serialport');
    var Readlines = serialport.parsers.Readline;
    var parser = new Readlines();
    var path = '/dev/ttyACM0';
    var myPort = new serialport(path ,{
        baudRate: 9600,
    });

    parser.on('data', readSerialData);
    myPort.pipe(parser);

    function readSerialData(data) {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO Temperature_Sensor (value) VALUES ("+ data 
    +")";
         con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log("record inserted");
    });
    console.log(data);
    sleep(1000);
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is it ok that you emit `readSerialData`  on `parser` before you declare it?

Comment: They are not. There are no parentheses, so they are not calling the function, only mentioning it.

Comment: What error message do you see? In the readSerialData function, is the value of data, legit?

Comment: if i run this it displays "data" but it seems to skip everything inside con.query()